# Definir Content-type Web API C#

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-web-api

Bom dia Pessoal, é o seguinte, estou criando uma Web API que deve receber alguns parâmetros entre eles uma imagem de formato binário com o content-type "octet-stream". Os demais parâmetros são enviados no endereço da chamada, exceto a imagem de acordo com a documentação da API. Gostaria de saber como posso receber esta imagem no meu controller. Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public class new_biometric_imageController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/new_biometric_image/{session}/{device_id}/{identifier_id}/{width}/{height}")]
    public IHttpActionResult new_biometric_image(string session, long device_id, long identifier_id, int width, int height, [FromBody] byte[] imagem)
    {
        try
        {



            return Ok("ok");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var mensagem = "Não foram encontrados usuarios!";

            return Ok(mensagem);
        }

    }

}
```

Porem ao realizar testes com o postman, ele recebe todos os outros parâmetros menos a imagem enviada, a opção escolhida no postman é no body:
[image: Postman]

Alguém sabe como posso resolver está situação? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Se os outros parâmetros vão vir da query, você pode adicionar o `[FromQuery]`... Essa rota não deveria estar na sua atcion ao invés da controller?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, obrigado por responder, no caso utilizo [FromQuery] na frente de todos da action? eu nunca utilizei este método, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre. Com relação ao [Route] realmente estava errado, já corrigi.